# Data search issue from mysql json data type

Tags: mysql, json, jsonschema

Please see folowing image

[image]

There are read three column return when I run following query

```
SELECT measurment_list_t, measurment_list 
    FROM products where measurment_list->'$.weight.value' > '300';
```

There are show two row by conditions but there are show three rows.

Why this is happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably because you are comparing strings, not integers.
Since the string '300' is sorted before all of '56', '356' and '756' you
see three rows. If you store the JSON numbers as integers instead or
explicitly CAST measurment_list->'$.weight.value' to UNSIGNED and then compare with 300 rather than '300', you should get only two rows.

Hope this helps,
Dag